# Assembly sending parameters - fastcall

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm trying to call my asm function from c++ and send two parameters which should be saved in ecx and edx according to wikipedia regarding the fastcall calling convension.

This does however not work. Am i missing something?

Assembly x86

```
.model flat

.code
_TestFunction proc

    mov eax, ecx
    add eax, edx
    ret

_TestFunction endp
end
```

C++ Code

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int TestFunction(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Function returns:" << TestFunction(200,100) << std::endl;
    
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The function returns 1 and this is the registers:

ECX = 00000000 EDX = 00000001

Build logs:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Tutorial, Configuration: Debug
> Win32 ------ 1>
> Assembling asm.asm... 1>
> Main.cpp 1>
> Tutorial.vcxproj -> C:\Users\nilo\documents\visual studio
> 2012\Projects\Tutorial\Debug\Tutorial.exe
>
> ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Ye i can see that the registers are empty. ECX = 00000000 EDX = 00000001

Comment: You have not stated `__fastcall` convention so why would the compiler use that method? Just from browsing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: I though MSVS compiler automatically used fastcall?

Comment: it looks like its using __cdecl calling convension. Changing to __fastcall results in unresolved external symbol. At least i know what the problem is. cheers

Comment: That's why I only use the stack to get the parameters : stack always works. With stack this problem would be resolved easily.

Comment: @nilo not posted as an answer because my comment was informed only by one minute's browsing.

Comment: I think i have confused the default calling convension from x64 with x86. Building my project for x64 showed indeed the right answer in the registers but not for the x86. My bad and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want the [__fastcall calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6xa169sk.aspx) in Win32, your code need small changes:

In the assembly file, change

```
_TestFunction proc
...
_TestFunction endp
```

to

```
@TestFunction@8 proc
...
@TestFunction@8 endp
```

In the C++ file, change

```
extern "C" int TestFunction(int a, int b);
```

to

```
extern "C" int __fastcall TestFunction(int a, int b);
```

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: I've tested it with and without VS 2010 Express. It works.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez. I've got some problems with the "right" place of `file.asm`, but I thought this is caused by my lack of experience with VS. Use a sniffer (e.g. [filemon](http://filemon.en.softonic.com/download)) to see where `ml.exe` looks for `file.asm`.

Comment: Hey mate. This actually solved the problem for the 32bits but i had to change @8 to @4.

Comment: @nilo: The suffix (@8) is the size of all arguments in bytes. "@8" means: two arguments à 4 bytes. If you need to change it to @4, this means that VS did recognize only one argument. Check your source code!

Comment: Makes perfect sense since i only send 1 int. Cheers mate that cleared up everything.